# How do I draw an US style negator on a node in tikzpicture environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw US style negator, I found one site where there is like names for all parts in schemes, but it keeps popping out error and it says that it can't recognize "american not port" and that's the same name for it as in the site I found. Maybe I added lines that are not necessary, but im new to latex, any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,automata,backgrounds,petri,patterns,shadows,fadings,calc,decorations,decorations.text,circuits.logic.US}

\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usepackage{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\tikzstyle{not_1} = [draw,not port, line width=0.75pt]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [<->,line width=3pt] (0,0) - - (0,-2);
    \draw [line width=0.5pt] (-1.5,0) - - (-1.5,-1);
    \draw [line width=0.5pt] (1.75,0) - - (1.75,-1);
    \draw node[](1.75,-1) (n1){};
    \draw (n1)node [not_1, rotate=-90](not1){}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: tip: you can use Ctrl-K or the little `{}` editor icon to quickly format the selection as code.

Comment: haha, thank you, I like edited it 5 times, and still it was all messed up

Comment: Did you try adding the `\usepackage{circuitikz}` in preamble?

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, I forgot to add that package, it's working fine now, just to rearange some coordinates, thanks for help

Comment: Your welcome, yes, rearange some coordinates. It looks bad :-)

Comment: @ferahfeza An answer?

Answer (score 1):

Add `\usepackage{circuitikz}` in preamble for circuit elements.

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,circuitikz}

%\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,automata,backgrounds,petri,patterns,shadows,fadings,calc,decorations,decorations.text,circuits.logic.US}

%\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
%\usepackage{calc}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\tikzstyle{not_1} = [draw,not port, line width=0.75pt]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [latex-latex,line width=3pt] (0,-1) -- (0,-3);
    \draw [line width=0.5pt] (-1.5,0) -- (-1.5,-1);
    \draw [line width=0.5pt] (1.75,0) -- (1.75,-1);
    \draw node[](1.75,-1) (n1){};
    \draw (n1)node [not_1, rotate=-90](not1){}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```